Как настроить Windows Defender чтобы он перестал удалять файлы?
На Windows 11 Microsoft Defender стал удалять файлы, которые считает заражёнными.
Я раньше настраивал его, чтобы он просто предупреждал и блокировал, но не удалял. А сейчас то ли что-то изменилось, то ли настройки сбились - не знаю, но он просто удаляет неугодные файлы. Не в карантин, а именно удалением.
Как настроить, чтобы перестал удалять?
Пытался нагуглить, но попадается только его полное отключение, добавление папок в исключения и восстановление файлов из карантина. Самое близкое, что нашёл - автоочистка карантина через групповые политики - кажется, я когда-то использовал групповые политики при его настройке.
В общем, мне надо, чтобы антивирус продолжал работать, но безвозвратно файлы не удалял. Желательно чтобы и в карантин не перемещал, а просто блокировал.

Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что вопрос не относится к задачам программирования и инструментам разработки

@Uranus, а с какой стати он должен к ним относиться? Он относится к администрированию.

Пробовал ChatGPT спросить? Я скопипастил вопрос, он дал ответ, выглядит хорошо. Но не могу оценить насколько это работает, не работаю с виндой

@Qwertiy, этот вопрос не относится ни к администрированию баз данных, ни к настройке физических и виртуальных серверов. Это вопрос по настройке конкретного приложения. В справке такие вопросы не включены в он-топик: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Заголовок вопроса тоже надо привести в порядок

хм. это шутка? заголовок про одно, вопрос про другое.

@Uranus, заголовок исправил.

@aleksandrbarakin, заголовок от сохранённого черновика остался, который я не стал спрашивать - не заметил просто. Исправил.

@Uranus настройка конкретного приложения является одним из видов администрирования сервера. Если вы такой же вредный как я - лучше поинтересуйтесь, например, почему вопросы про 3D-моделирование считаются онтопиком https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8018

@TotalPusher, не пробовал, теперь попробовал спросить you com - вот его правдоподобный ответ: https://i.sstatic.net/5POpBGHO.png. А теперь предлагаю найти в настройках пункт, о котором он пишет - вот скриншот: https://i.sstatic.net/HCgImtOy.png. Правдоподобность и правильность - это далеко не одно и то же.
